# What would be the URL to display the Wordpress image editor with an image from the media library?

Tags: media-library

I want to be able to call the Media Library image editor from my plugin. From what I can see looking at the console that it is passing a URL like so http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?action=image-editor&_ajax_nonce=aa3dbd63c2&postid=551&do=open. But I have not been able to make this work. Does anyone know how it would be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the edit link to your image is:

```
http://example.tld/wp-admin/post.php?post=551&action=edit
```

then the link to the *image editor* for that image is:

```
http://example.tld/wp-admin/post.php?post=551&action=edit&image-editor
```

The `$_GET['image-editor']` is checked for in the [`edit_form_image_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/edit_form_image_editor/) function.

*PS: I first noticed this trick, when testing [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-user-profile-photo/) avatar plugin recently (I'm not related to that plugin)*

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. Now I need to figure out how to add a link to the image editor to get back to the plugin page. That is another question I'll post.